# Find the differences - 14x14 Images

Tags: php

I have 23 images, they all are 14 pixels x 14 pixels.

In each one there's a letter on a white background (255 255 255 RGB).

I want to compare them and find unique blank pixels to identify that letter.

For example after that comparing procedure I would like to say that a image 14x14 that has the pixel number (3 width, 2 height) white is an "A" for sure.

Is it possible?

I have the main loop to check every pixel but I'm stuck now:

```
function getpixelat($img,$x,$y) {
    $rgb = imagecolorat($img,$x,$y);
    $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
    $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
    $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
    return $r.$g.$b;
}

for( $y=$inity; $y<$h; $y++) {
   for( $x=$initx; $x<$w; $x++) {
       $pixel = getpixelat($img,$x,$y);
    }
}
```

Comment: why did I get the -1? Isn't this a valid question?

Comment: voted down without ever leaving a comment is such a cruel deed,+1 to undo

Comment: I've not voted, but your question is either really broad, or really narrow. You're asking about OCR, essentially, which is a solved problem. So the answer is yes, it is possible. Use a library.

Comment: Why use OCR? Can't be solved with a loop and an array? The images are always the same.

Comment: If the images are always the same then why no create arrays with the various expected data values and compare them to the image data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find unique blank pixels for a particular letter:

1. You would want to create mask for each letter. Start with a blank mask, e.g. 14x14 array with all entries set to zero.
2. Then, for the letter in question (e.g. A), mark each pixel you know is blank.
3. For all the remaining letters, compare it to the mask for A. If any other letter has the same blank pixel, mark that pixel as not usable.
4. Repeat the process on all the other letters, i.e. compare each letter to every other letter.

Once you have a complete set of masks for all letters, compare each mask to every other mask to ensure that you do not have any duplicates. If you don't, you may have something you can refer to, to determine which letter you are dealing with.